# Add child node to TreeView programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have this code in aspx page:

```
<asp:TreeView ShowCheckBoxes="All" runat="server" ID="TreeView2">
<Nodes>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Home" NavigateUrl="~/Home.aspx" Target="_blank" />
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Employee" Value="Employee" NavigateUrl="~/Employee.aspx" Target="_blank">
        <asp:TreeNode Text="UploadResume" Value="UploadResume"   NavigateUrl="~/Upload_Resume.aspx" Target="_blank" />
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Edit Resume" NavigateUrl="~/Edit_Resume.aspx" Target="_blank" />
        <asp:TreeNode Text="View Resume" NavigateUrl="~/View_Resume.aspx" Target="_blank" />
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Employer" NavigateUrl="~/Employer.aspx" Target="_blank">
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Upload Job" NavigateUrl="~/Upload_Job.aspx" Target="_blank" />
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Edit Job" NavigateUrl="~/Edit_Job.aspx" Target="_blank" />
        <asp:TreeNode Text="View Job" NavigateUrl="~/View_Job.aspx" Target="_blank" />
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Admin" NavigateUrl="~/Admin.aspx" Target="_blank">
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Add User" NavigateUrl="~/Add_User.aspx" Target="_blank" />
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Edit User" NavigateUrl="~/Edit_Use.aspx" Target="_blank" />
        <asp:TreeNode Text="View User" NavigateUrl="~/View_User.aspx" Target="_blank" />
    </asp:TreeNode>
</Nodes>
```

I want to add child node to `UploadResume` in `Page_Load`. I used this code but error occurred run-time:
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to show us the code in your page_Load.

Comment: @artm `TreeView2.FindNode("UploadResume").ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("majid", "majid"));`

Comment: UploadResume is a child of Employee node, so find the Employee node first and then UploadResume from its children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `UploadResume` is a child of `Employee` node change `TreeView2.FindNode()` like this:

```
TreeView2.FindNode("Employee").ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("majid", "majid"));
```